# OnActivityResult is not called in a Fragment inside another Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-nested-fragment

I have two fragments with names F1 and F2 and an activity named A.
I added fragment F1 in a `Framelayout` inside activity A using something like this:

```
F1 fragment = new F1();
FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
transaction.replace(R.id.main_drawer_frame, F1, LEFT_DRAWER_FRAGMENT);
transaction.commit();
```

Then inside fragment F1 I added fragment F2 in another layout:

```
F2 fragment = new F2();
fragment.setTargetFragment(this, 0); //"this" refer to an instance of F1
FragmentTransaction transacton = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
transacton.replace(R.id.drawer_host_frame, fragment, CURRENT_FRAGMENT);
transacton.commit();
```

Then I start an Activity from F2 using `startActivityForResult()`:

```
startActivityForResult(getActivity(), intent, REQUEST_ACCOUNT);
```

And then I overrided `onActivityResult()` inside fragment F2. but the problem is onActivityResult() is never called. then I figured out that `super.onActivityResult()` inside fragment F1 don't trigger `onActivtyResult()` inside fragment F2.

I can manually retrieve every Fragment inside getChildFragmentManager() and then call `onActivityResult()` on them, but its clumsy and is like I'm just leaving the real problem unsolved.

Comment: possible duplicate of [onActivityResult not being called in Fragment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6147884/onactivityresult-not-being-called-in-fragment)

Comment: NOOOOO, It's not duplicate at all, You better first read my question then decide to ruin it. :(

Comment: Please remove duplicate tag...

Answer (score 3):

As I said one way is to use something like this inside fragment F1:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    //Here catch every requestCode for parentFragment
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    for (Fragment fragment : getChildFragmentManager().getFragments())
       if (fragment != null)
           fragment.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Parent fragment F1 will receive onActivityResult,F2 will not. F1 can find F2 fragment and then call its method to get the tasks done.